# NSDateFormatter dateFromString is nil with 2015-10-05

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

Is it only my XCode/computer/iOS Device that gets nil with this code? This is CRAZY!

```
NSDateFormatter *f = [NSDateFormatter new];
[f setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
id ret = [f dateFromString:@"2014-10-05"];
NSLog(@"date = %@", ret);
```

This is the log from my console:

2015-04-06 21:35:22.899 test[665:222261] date = (null)

BTW: it's a NEW project, and I get both on the simulator and on my iPhone.

Comment: I get: "date = 2014-10-05 04:00:00 +0000", i'm in EDT. Don't use `id`, the compiler can't type-check.

Comment: Wooow. It's getting more and more weird. I started a project from scratch and get the same result: (null)

Comment: Yeah, but for this example I don't care about type-check

Comment: Yeah, it is just code hygiene, why be concerned about other readers.

Comment: I am use your code and i ptint the log and i get the perfect date
"2015-04-07 10:53:33.014 test[514:9737] date = 2014-10-04 18:30:00 +0000"

Comment: This code is correct. i have run this code and get output :                      date = 2014-10-04 18:30:00 +0000

Comment: This code is working correct on both Xcode 5 and Xcode 6.

Comment: In my XCode it doesn't work. It's nil

Answer (score 0):

It's some bug related to localTimeZone, check this:

```
NSDateFormatter *f = [NSDateFormatter new];
NSTimeZone *local = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSLog(@"secondsFromGMT = %ld", [local secondsFromGMT]); // this is -14400
[f setTimeZone:local];

NSDate *ret = [f dateFromString:@"2014-10-05"];
NSLog(@"date = %@", ret); // this is nil

[f setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:-14400]];
[f setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
ret = [f dateFromString:@"2014-10-05"];
NSLog(@"date = %@", ret); // this is 2014-10-05 04:00:00 +0000
```

I ended up doing this in my code:

```
NSDateFormatter *f = [NSDateFormatter new];
NSTimeZone *z = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
z = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:z.secondsFromGMT];
[f setTimeZone:z];
// use f here no problem
```

Comment: You should not need to set timezone like that.  Probably something's mucked up with your system configuration.

Comment: Yeah, I know it shouldn't, but it needs it, otherwise it doesn't work. I'm working on an App and we're doing beta testing and the same thing happened on a lot of people's iPhones, so, this is a bug, clearly.